# WordPress auto login form fill button

Tags: wordpress, authentication, button, plugins

Can I apply it in WordPress like the entry of the site I have given below? There are many plugins on this subject but they don't meet my needs.
ex: http://example.com/wp-login.php?autologin=demo
I don't want a long link like this, I will login normally
ex: http://example.com/wp-admin/
Then there will be login buttons Admin, Store Manager, User
Whatever button I press, that username and password will automatically enter
I want to do the same site entry below in WordPress.

Sample Site : https://demo.smart-school.in/site/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish that, you should make a copy of `wp-login.php` and add the buttons yourself. With the help of JavaScript you could code something like this:

```
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Administrator</button></p>
```

This creates a button.

```
<div id="myDIV">name@example.com</div>
```

And this is the text you want to change.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "name@example.com") {
    x.innerHTML = "name2@example.com";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "name@example.com";
  }
}
</script>
```

Changing the text is possible with this script.

Another way of accomplishing this is by creating custom login links. I think this is going to be the easiest option for you. With a plugin like 'Autologin Links' (https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/autologin-links/) you can create automatic login links for all users.

Connect the links, like this, to different buttons and you are ready to go.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/page1'">Superuser</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='/page2'">Admin</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='/page3'">Viewer</button>
```

Comment: I don't know much about how to do it, The codes you have given are useful and I'll work on them. I tried the plug but what I want is not a link link, to use javascript as in the example site, Is it possible to make your code as add-ons?, Thank you very much for a helpful answer

Comment: It would surely be possible to convert these kinds of scrips into a Wordpress plugin, but -sadly -  I have no experience creating plugins. Besides, I do not think a lot of sites would use such a plugin, because automatically filling in login info is kind of a security flaw.